# Turning off .on when clicking link

Tags: jquery, swipe

I have created the following code that works for what I need with the `.on` function but when I click my `#close_box` link how do I set what I just put `.on` to `.off` so it won't run against unless I click the `.mcndiv` link?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".mcndiv").click(function() {
    // Bind the swipeHandler callback function to the swipe event on div.box
    $("#mc-container").on("swipeleft", swipingLeft);
    $("#mc-container").on("swiperight", swipingRight);
    // Callback function references the event target and adds the 'swipe' class to it
    function swipingLeft() {
      $('#mcnumbers-links #mcnumbers-colours a.mcselected').removeClass('mcselected')
    }

    function swipingRight() {
      $('#mcnumbers-links #mcnumbers-colours a.mcselected').addClass('mcselected')
    }
    $('#close_box').click(function() {
      $("#mc-container").off("swipeleft", swipingLeft);
      $("#mc-container").off("swiperight", swipingRight);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.mcselected {
  background: blue;
}

a {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  background: green;
}

.mcndiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mcnumbers-ulinside">
<li id="mcnumbers-container"></li>
<li id="mcnumbers-container">
  <a href="#" class="mcndiv">
random link
  </a>
</li>
<li id="mcnumbers-container"></li>
</div>

<div id="mc-container">
    <div id="mcnumbers-links">
      <div id="mcnumbers-colours"></div>
      <div id="mcnumbers-colours">
          <a href="#" class="b_dtl">a</a>
      </div>
      <div id="mcnumbers-colours">
        <a href="#" class="b_dtl mcselected">b</a>
      </div>
      <div id="mcnumbers-colours"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

I tried to get the mobile jquery to work in the example but it's not working.. on my localhost site it is? But trying to get the .on to become .off if that makes sense? So if I swipe after I have clicked #close_box it does nothing?

Thanks heaps :)

Comment: whats your html code?

Comment: The code should already do that, because `.off("swipeleft")` and `.off("swiperight")` will remove all callbacks assigned to `swipeleft` and `swiperight`. So the reason for your problem has to be within your html code or in another script.

Comment: Thanks I tried to update some code let me know if this helps? Cheers

Comment: There is no `#close_box` in your code. So I would guess that it is not  in the DOM at the time you try to register the `click` event. What does `console.log('number of #close_box: '+$('[id="close_box"]').length)` show you if you place it right before the `$('#close_box').click(function() {` . Beside that: ids have to be unique, but you have multiple elements with the same id: `mcnumbers-colours`,  `mcnumbers-container` this might also be the reason why your code does not work, you should use classes instead of ids in that case.

Comment: You should not use same id `close_box` on many elements, ID should be unique on page, therefor use some class or element attribute.